# Getting a keyerror python when trying to add a new key to a Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

In the next code, I'm getting a KeyError when I'm trying to add a new key to a dictionary.

```
def tournamentWinner(competitions, results):
    record = {}
    winner = None
    for i in range(len(results)):
        if results[i] == 0:
            if record[competitions[i][1]] not in record:
                record[competitions[i][1]] = 3
            else:
                record[competitions[i][1]] += 3
        else:
            if record[competitions[i][0]] not in record:
                record[competitions[i][0]] = 3
            else:
                record[competitions[i][0]] += 3
    for element in record:
        if winner is None:
            winner = element
        if element > winner:
            winner = elemnt
    return winner
```

I am getting this KeyError:

```
Exception Detected: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tester/program.py", line 7, in tournamentWinner
    if record[competitions[i][1]] not in record:
KeyError: 'C#'
```

Comment: You're seeing if the value of `record[competitions[i][1]]` is part of record. Not if `competitions[i][1]` is in record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because `competitions[i][1]` key doesn't exist in `record` at the time you check for it with if-else.

You can get around this problem by using `dict.get` method:

Instead of this if-else:

```
if record[competitions[i][1]] not in record:
                record[competitions[i][1]] = 3
            else:
                record[competitions[i][1]] += 3
```

you can use

```
record[competitions[i][1]] = record.get(competitions[i][1], 0) + 3
```